terra FLT4S datatype error when reprojecting
I'm using the 'terra' package to read, reproject, and extract raster values. One of my rasters is a date (yyyymmdd, 20200822) layer, as an 'FLT4S' (though I've tried other datatype formats). When I read the raster, cell values are correct. When I reproject the raster (method = "nearest"), the raster cell values are incorrect, usually rounded to the nearest factor of 2 (20200805 = 202008006).
> test <- rast(r"(...\{9FA74D0C-BACB-4B2C-8AC5-D4CCDB5C8C8C}_1_dob_tmp.tif)")
> unique(test)

          z
1  20180715
2  20180716
3  20180717
4  20180718
5  20180719
6  20180720
...


> project(test, "epsg:26910") %>%
+     unique()

          z
1  20180716
2  20180718
3  20180720
4  20180722
5  20180724
6  20180726
...

though if I shorten the data to 6-digits, the issue is resolved
test <- test - 20000000

> project(test, "epsg:26910") %>%
+     unique()

        z
1  180715
2  180716
3  180717
4  180718
5  180719
6  180720
...


This is not a solution I'd like to resort to. Any ideas as to why project() is having trouble with the larger cell values?
R version 4.4.1 (2024-06-14 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19045)

Matrix products: default


locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.utf8  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.utf8    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.utf8
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.utf8    

time zone: America/Los_Angeles
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] tools     stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] sp_2.1-4        lubridate_1.9.3 leaflet_2.2.2   sf_1.0-16       terra_1.7-78    dplyr_1.1.4     knitr_1.48   


@LTyrone the the "near" method is best for this situation as I don't want to create fractional dates during the reprojection (ie. 20200805.22). So, it is best to think of the data as categorical/discrete.
To clarify, the rasters are of wildfire progression with large areas of pixels as the same value. Regardless of the artifacts from raster re-projection, I'm still encountering this issue.

@LTyrone thanks for the info, as you surmised I'm new to stack overflow. This will replicate the problemo:
`test <- rast(nrows= 100, ncols=100)
crs(test) <- "epsg:4326"
test[] <- sample(20200101:20200199, size = ncell(test), replace = T)
unique(test)
project(test, "epsg:26910") %>%
unique()`

FYI project(raster, 'projection', use_gdal = FALSE) seems to be an effective fix.

Good to know. You could also try test[] <- as.Date(as.character(test[]), "%Y%m%d") to convert your integers to as.Date(), then r1 <- project(test, "EPSG:26910"), then r1[] <- as.integer(format(as.Date(r1[]), "%Y%m%d")) to change them back to integers. Let me know if that works for your real data and I'll post it as an answer. Also, your example data isn't quite representative as I'm pretty sure January only has 31 days ;)
